# Python getting hour from from timestamp

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

I need to classify timestamps based on the hour, for example if it is between 7 AM and 9 AM, it will be morning. I have timestamps that I take from my csv file and I need to get only hour so I can classify the number with if statements.

I will take the timestamps from **date** column and create a new column named **hour**,

```
df['hour'] = df.date.dt.hour
```

but it gives me the following error: **AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values**

Timestamps are like the following: 2016-03-14 17:24:55

Comment: you have to first convert date-column to datetime like this:  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of object is `df` but you could convert timestamps to `datetime` objects and then use attributes of datetime objects to access timestamp attributes:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime('2016-03-14 17:24:55', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['hour'] = d.hour
```

You can read more about `datetime` module [at this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your 'date' columnn to a datatime object first:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `datetime` object with the timestamp string extracted from your CSV input data:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: s = '2016-03-14 17:24:55'

In [3]: d = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(s)

In [4]: d.hour
Out[4]: 17
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get an `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` is most likely because that particular series is not of `datetime` object type.

Like the error states, .dt attribute is available for datetime objects. So first thing to do is check the `type` of entries. 
Suppose the values are not datetime objects then to convert it,

specify `datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` and use .dt the following way to get time values:

```
data['start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_datetime'], format=datetime_format)
h = data['start_datetime'].dt.hour
m = data['start_datetime'].dt.minute
s = data['start_datetime'].dt.second
```