# How to convert outcome of timedelta into only hours

Tags: python, datetime

The outcome for duration I got includes days, hours and minutes. What can I do to make it shows only hours ?

```
import datetime as dt

start_datetime_str = '1/04/2021 7:55'
end_datetime_str = '14/05/2021 9:55'

# convert string to date object
start_datetime_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(start_datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
end_datetime_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(end_datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

# calculate duration
duration = end_datetime_obj - start_datetime_obj
print(duration)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python getting hour from from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229256/python-getting-hour-from-from-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use total_seconds() and devide 60 two times to get hours from seconds

```
print(duration.total_seconds()/60/60)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.hour`:

```
duration = end_datetime_obj.hour - start_datetime_obj.hour
print(duration)
```

Output:

```
2
```